# Border and spacing between TDs. Need help

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have a table with 2 columns. 1 for text and another for image. 
I have repeated border style like border-left, border-right etc.

**Is there any way like border:0 0 1 0; ? so that I don't repeated the whole style applied on below cell. Any better way.**

**I have little spacing between TDs. I don't want it. Anyone tell me how to remove spacing please.**

*Anyone got any better styling skills to achive same thing more cleaner.*

http://jsfiddle.net/pauldwaite/kYAMX/

**CSS**

```
.ver-mainbox-table{width:898px;  }
.ver-mainbox-tr{height:122px; background-color:#ffffff; }
.ver-mainbox-txt{vertical-align:middle; padding:0 0 0 10px; width:500px; border-top:1px solid #c3c3c3; border-left:1px solid #c3c3c3; border-bottom:1px solid #c3c3c3; }
.ver-mainbox-img{vertical-align:middle; padding:2px 2px 2px 0; width:186px; text-align:right; border-top:1px solid #c3c3c3; border-right:1px solid #c3c3c3; border-bottom:1px solid #c3c3c3;}
.spacer-m{height: 15px;}
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="ver-mainbox-table">
            <tr class="ver-mainbox-tr">
                <td class="ver-mainbox-txt">
                    sdf sdf sdf sfd sdf
                </td>               
                <td class="ver-mainbox-img">
                    <img src="v1.gif" alt="" title="" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td class="spacer-m" colspan="2"></td></tr>
            <tr class="ver-mainbox-tr">
                <td class="ver-mainbox-txt">
                    <h2>Immunizations</h2>
                </td>               
                <td class="ver-mainbox-img">
                    <img src="v1.gif" alt="" title="" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine most of your values into a single statment:

```
border:1px solid #c3c3c3
```

You can then specify the border widths for those you want  to have a value of 0.

```
border-width:0 0 1px 0;
```

To get rid of the spacing between the `td`'s you can use the `border-collapse` property with a value of `collapse`;

```
border-collapse:collapse;
```

Answer (score 1):

The CSS style you're looking for to remove the spacing between table cells is `border-collapse`. You apply it to the `<table>` element like so:

```
table {
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

(note: replace `table` with a better selector if you don't want it to apply to all tables)

But unless I'm misunderstanding your context, I don't think you really need to use a table for this sort of thing. In fact, if it isn't tabular data, it's preferable not to use a table.

You could do something like this instead:

```
<div>
   <span>sdf sdf sdf sfd sdf</span><img src="v1.gif" alt="" title="" />
</div>
<div>
   <span>Immunizations</span><img src="v1.gif" alt="" title="" />
</div>
```

Then all you need to do is style the `<spans>` to have a fixed width, and you should have pretty much the same effect:

```
span {
  display:inline-block;
  width:500px;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I can not use span or DIV. This is used in CMS and it hard to work with DIVs when editing text etc. This is like tabular data because will be using many rows consisting text and image.

Answer (score 0):

The remaining space is probably `margin`. To remove *all* spacing:

```
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
```

Then you can adjust from there to get the layout you want.

To clean up your borders:

```
border-style: solid;
border-color: #c3c3c3;
border-width: 1px 0 1px 1px;  /* top right bottom left */
```

It's the same number of properties, but looks a little cleaner IMO.

Comment: I think the issue of spacing between td's is more likely to be the border collapse than margin.

Comment: "The remaining space is probably `margin`" - not on table cells it's not.